# How was this theorem re-written to achieve the given alternate forms?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

I was given the following theorem:

> Suppose that if $G$ is cyclic, then either $G$ is abelian or $G$ has order $24$. Suppose also that either $G$ is cyclic or both $H$ is normal and $G$ is abelian. And suppose that $H$ is not normal. Then if $G$ doesn't have order $24$, $G$ is abelian.

And asked to "fill in the blanks" such that the theorems below are equivalent to that given above:

> **Thm 1:** Suppose that if $G$ is cyclic, then either $G$ is abelian or $G$ has order $24$. Suppose either  $G$ is cyclic or both $H$ is normal and $G$ is abelian. Suppose that $G$ doesn't have order $24$. Then either ___ [2] or ___ [1].

> **Thm 2:** Suppose that if $G$ is cyclic, then either $G$ is abelian or $G$ has order $24$. Suppose either $G$ is cyclic or both $H$ is normal and $G$ is abelian. Suppose $H$ is not normal, $G$ is not abelian, and ____ [2]. Then both $G$ is cyclic and $G$ is not cyclic.

---

I "filled in the blanks" as follows:

[1] $G$ is abelian, [2] $H$ is not normal

[3] $G$ has order $24$

It seems, however, that the correct answers are:

[1] $G$ is abelian, [2] $H$ is normal

[3] $G$ does not have order $24$

---

I don't understand how the correct answers were achieved.

This is a course in mathematical logic$-$ while I have had enough group theory to know what most of the terms used mean, no background whatsoever in higher math or group theory is expected or intended to be necessary to solve these problems.

My approach was to write the theorems "symbolically" (e.g. let the proposition $x$ be "$G$ is cyclic"...), and then manipulate them to obtain forms 1 and 2.

**How can the correct answers be found?**

Comment: The first "is" in the final sentence of the quoted "theorem"... should that be an "if"? Also, I don't think this is about group theory at all. The actual meaning of the statements in question is irrelevant (for one thing, one does not have to "suppose" that if $G$ is cyclic then it is abelian... *that's* a theorem!)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oops! Yes, that "is" should be an "if" (corrected). Yes, this uses terminology from group theory but is supposed to be solvable without knowing anything whatsoever about the subject (perhaps, then, it would be more appropriate to remove the [group-theory] tag).

Comment: Yes; that was my point. It has nothing to do with group theory. Thanks for removing the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* about group theory. This is purely about propositional calculus. The actual meaning of the sentences here is irrelevant (and rather silly from a Group Theory point of view...)

- Let $\mathbf{C}$ stand for "$G$ is cyclic."
- Let $\mathbf{A}$ stand for "$G$ is abelian."
- Let $\mathbf{T}$ stand for "$G$ has order $24$" ($\mathbf{T}$ for "twenty-four").
- Let $\mathbf{N}$ stand for "$H$ is normal."

Your premises are:

1. $\mathbf{C}\longrightarrow (\mathbf{A}\vee \mathbf{T})$.
2. $\mathbf{C} \vee (\mathbf{N}\wedge \mathbf{A})$.
3. $\neg\mathbf{N}$.

You are asked to conclude that $\neg\mathbf{T}\longrightarrow \mathbf{A}$.

From $\neg\mathbf{N}$ you can conclude that $\neg\mathbf{N}\vee \neg\mathbf{A}$. This is equivalent to $\neg(\mathbf{N}\wedge \mathbf{A})$. From this and 2 you can use Disjunction to conclude $\mathbf{C}$. From this and 1, by Modus Ponens, you may conclude that $\mathbf{A}\vee\mathbf{T}$. But this is equivalent to $\neg\mathbf{T}\longrightarrow \mathbf{A}$, which gives what you want. So the first "theorem" is valid.

Now, your "Theorem 1" has the following premises:

1. $\mathbf{C}\longrightarrow (\mathbf{A}\vee\mathbf{T})$.
2. $\mathbf{C}\vee (\mathbf{N}\wedge\mathbf{A})$.
3. $\neg\mathbf{T}$.

and you are asked to write the conclusion as a disjunction.
You propose $\mathbf{A}\wedge(\neg\mathbf{N})$. Does this follow? No: if $\mathbf{C}$, $\mathbf{N}$, and $\mathbf{A}$ are all true, but $\mathbf{T}$ is false, then the premises hold, but your conclusion does not. So this is not even a valid conclusion.

We can think of the first theorem as having 1 and 2 as premises, and then having as a conclusion
$$\neg\mathbf{N}\longrightarrow (\neg\mathbf{T}\longrightarrow A).\tag{1}$$
We want to rewrite it as an implication with premise $\neg\mathbf{T}$ and consequent a disjunction.

Well, $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$\mathbf{N}\vee (\neg\mathbf{T}\longrightarrow \mathbf{A})$$
which in turn is equivalent to
$$\mathbf{N}\vee(\mathbf{T}\vee\mathbf{A})$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\mathbf{T}\vee(\mathbf{N}\vee\mathbf{A})$$
which is equivalent to
$$\neg\mathbf{T}\longrightarrow(\mathbf{N}\vee\mathbf{A})$$
which gives the desired form of the conclusion: so the blanks should be filled with $\mathbf{N}\vee\mathbf{A}$ ("either  $H$ is normal, or $G$ is abelian"), just as it was stated.

I'll leave you to try the second one using these ideas.